How to prompt from user to edit a variable in python with befor instance?
I want to when I ask user to edit not just print to please prompt show the before value for edit.
for example:
a = "i am very happy"
b = input("enter an string for editing a: ")
a = b

What is I am expected from my code to show:
enter an string for editing a: i am very happy


I don't think that python can do what you want. The input() function only ever accepts new data and does not allow you to edit some existing data.

Do you just want to print out the current value of a, or do you want that stuff to be editable?

As @quamrana mentioned, the user will not be able to "edit" the printed string. But if by "edit" you mean ask the user to enter a new value and you want to print the old value, then just input("enter an string for editing a: " + a).

Does this answer your question? Python: how to modify/edit the string printed to screen and read it back?
